# No paypal account for a secondary receiver in a Paypal Adaptive Transaction

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

What happens in the case the secondary receiver in my transaction doesn't have a Paypal account.
Will he receive a notification asking him to create a Paypal account, or will the API call not succeed?

I have little way to know if the user selling services has got a Paypal account when he registers to my platform.

Also, does it have to be a Business account in order to receive money, or can it be a personal account?
Freelancer mostly will be using this on a one-time basis.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The application owner must have a PayPal Business account. Senders and (secondary) receivers are not 
required to have PayPal accounts initially. PayPal prompts a sender to create 
an account before a payment can be completed. A receiver must create an 
account to receive the funds after the payment completes.

Also, [GetVerifiedStatus](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/) API will help you determine what type of account the user has and if it is verified or not.